# How to restrict the field in Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I have to restrict some field which are there in processtemplate class. Below is the method which i have developed. When i pass some id it gives me runtime exception. Please help me out

```
    public ProcessTemplate get(String id) throws GRIDRecordsDataManagerException {
    ProcessTemplate entity = null;
    try {

        BasicDBObject qry = new BasicDBObject();
        Map<String, Object> whereMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        whereMap.put("id", id);
        qry.putAll(whereMap);
        BasicDBObject field = new BasicDBObject();
        field.put("name", 1);
        field.put("status", 1);
        field.put("description", 1);

        DBCursor results = dbCollection.find(qry, field);

        if (results != null && results.hasNext()) {
            DBObject dbObj = results.next();
            entity = new ProcessTemplate();
            entity.setId((String) dbObj.get("id"));
            entity.setProcessName((String) dbObj.get("name"));
            entity.setStatus((String) dbObj.get("status"));
            entity.setDescription((String) dbObj.get("description"));

            System.out.println(entity);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return entity;
}
```

Comment: Where is the null pointer exception being thrown? What line, Could you please paste error trace?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: can't load partial GridFSFile file
 at com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSFile.markAsPartialObject(GridFSFile.java:266)
 at com.mongodb.DBCursor._next(DBCursor.java:514)
 at com.mongodb.DBCursor.next(DBCursor.java:581)
 at com.landisgyr.adms.scheduler.dao.ProcessTemplateMongoStore.get(ProcessTemplateMongoStore.java:104)
 at com.landisgyr.adms.scheduler.dao.Main.main(Main.java:11)

Comment: this is not a null pointer exception but a RuntimeException

Comment: ya. Any idea how to resolve that one

Comment: does it work if you remove the projection? I mean ```dbCollection.find(qry);```

Comment: it works if i remove the field .

Comment: Did the answer helped you or the problem is still there?

Comment: have you tried ```dbCollection.setObjectClass(null);``` What's happening then?

Answer (score 1):

Answer copied from [jira.mongodb.org](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1180)

> When querying a GridFS collection on specific fields, it works when no
>   GridFS file was ever stored on that collection. Once a file was saved
>   to the collection, the query on specific fields fails with "can't load
>   partial GridFSFile file".
>
> ...
>
> For now I'll reset the object associated with the collection, quite a
>   hack though: if (Objects.equal(GridFSDBFile.class,
>   coll.getObjectClass())) { coll.setObjectClass(null); }
>
> ...
>
> Hi, A collection can have an associated ObjectClass and this
>   information is cached, allowing it to be set once and then reused
>   elsewhere in your code. Once it is set you have to explicitly unset
>   it. GridFS is a specification for storing and retrieving files that is
>   built upon the driver. GridFS is opinionated about how it is to be
>   used, as such it sets the ObjectClass for the files collection when
>   you create a GridFS instance. The reason it throws an error is the
>   GridFSFile is not expected to be used in the way you've show as it
>   could represent a partial part of a file and which is why it throws
>   the "can't load partial GridFSFile file" runtime error. As you've
>   found out the associated ObjectClass can only unset by resetting the
>   ObjectClass back to null.

In your case it is translated to:

```
BasicDBObject qry = new BasicDBObject("id",id); //You can save 3 lines of code here, btw
BasicDBObject field = new BasicDBObject();
...
if (Objects.equal(GridFSDBFile.class, dbCollection.getObjectClass()))
 dbCollection.setObjectClass(null); 
DBCursor results = dbCollection.find(qry, field);
...
```